# iOS - Internationalisation and Localization

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, xcode7.3

Is it possible to change App language on Button tap ? I'm developing an App which should support multi languages and inside the App, there is option to choose the language (in the form of button). By default, App placeholder text will be in English, once the user choose some other language, placeholder text should change as per the language selected. I have gone through few examples in Internet, i couldn't find anything close to my requirement. I have seen example from appcoda and ray, but switching the language within the app is not provided. can somebody tell me how to achieve this ?

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: Ok, you have to do some extra coding from your end. First create a string file or any header file that will contain mapping between english words to another words. When you press the button, you have to create conditions to display text  in other language and it would be done via mapping of eng word to other language word.

Comment: Yes i have already created localisable string and it works perfectly when i change the region and language in edit scheme. How can i change the language on button tap ?

Comment: you have to just get the value for corresponding keys as we do in Dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Gagan_iOS. Every time i make changes in the localized string file, i had to remove the app from the simulator or device and run again. It is working now. Thanks !